# Silverlight service codegen only creates Async function calls? (SLsvcUtil.exe)

Tags: silverlight, wcf, asynchronous

I am using the Silverlight WCF service code gen tool (SLsvcUtil.exe) to take a WCF .svc and create a class to consume it.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197958(v=vs.95).aspx

The code it generates only has Async function calls. Is there a way to get synchronous calls generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. Silverlight doesn't allow synchronous calls, to avoid locking up the browser.  It needs to be a good plug-in citizen.  At any rate, synchronous calls are only good for the developer, not the user.  You want to avoid locking up the UI in your applications anyway.  Silverlight just forces you to take on these better practises.

Hope this helps...

Chris